# How do I create a Calculated Table of Medians for Grouped Data? (Power BI Desktop)

Tags: powerbi

If anyone can suggest a solution I would appreciate it. I would like to know how to create a calculated table that calculates the median for data grouped by three factors: Year, PeerGroup, and AssetClass.

[image]

Comment: Will a calculated column work instead of calculated table? Your table doesn't seems to have any unique column value.

Answer (score 0):

The DAXPatterns.com site has a write up of how to create a median function: 
http://www.daxpatterns.com/statistical-patterns/#median22

The function they demonstrate should give you the median for each grouping context - so it should plug right into your table.